# plt.bar doesnt connect with click event (or any event) - python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I keep looking example online and they seem to be about the same. When I try a small example it works, but for some reason I haven't gotten plt.bar to work. (I'm using jupyter notebook).

Here is how I'm displaying the graph:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

xpos = np.arange(len(df.T.mean()))
plt.bar(xpos, df.T.mean(), yerr=yerr, color=bar_colors, width=1, capsize=30, picker=True )
```

Here is my on_click function:

```
def on_click(event):
    plt.cla()
    plt.gca().set_title("please just work")
```

And here is how I'm hooking it up:

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_click)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_click)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', on_click)

#or the same with plt.gcf()
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_click)
```

How do I detect the click events on a bar graph?

**Edit**

I forgot to clarify that I'm just trying to hook up the click event at this point. Yes my click event should only clear the graph now, but there nothing is happening at all.

**Second Edit**

```
Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 4.2.3 and is running on:
Python 3.6.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2017, 22:59:30) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]

Current Kernel Information:
Python 3.6.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2017, 22:59:30) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: You forgot to redraw  the canvas after changing it.

Comment: I'm confused by the `plt.cla()` in your `on_click()` function. If you clear the axes, then there are no more artists to pick, and therefore your function cannot be triggered anymore

Comment: I was just trying to see anything from the function. So I was expecting a blank graph. That was just the most visually obvious think that I could think of.

Comment: Sorry I just have specified that all I'm trying to accomplish right now is to hook up the click event. I just want to see something happening, and then I'll make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: Does anybody know where can I see my jupyter console version? I don't have it installed in my machine I just use the online version

Comment: You probably haven't selected any interactive backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me on jupyter notebook using the `notebook` backend.

If this is not working for you, you may have to switch from `%matplotlib inline` to `%matplotlib notebook`

```
def on_click(event):
    plt.gca().set_title("Click at {:.2f}/{:.2f}\non {:s}".format(event.mouseevent.x, event.mouseevent.y, event.artist.__repr__()))
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()  # doesn't seem to be absolutely required,
                                  # but doesn't hurt to put it in


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), picker=True)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_click)
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the canvas redrawing itself. See first comment.

Comment: fair enough, it is not required on my machine, but maybe that's what causing problem on the OP's

Comment: It's not required in the current implementation of the notebook backend but that's surely not universal.

Comment: Ok so I pasted this code to my jupyter console, and it doesn't display anything. I have to add `plt.show()` which is also what I'm doing on my own. After adding `plt.show`, I'm seeing the same problem. Nothing seems to trigger. Maybe `plt.show` is a problem?

Comment: Are you using the notebook backend (%matplotlib notebook) or the inline backend (%matplotlin inline)?

Comment: @DizietAsahi module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline.

Comment: So I went on a thanksgiving break, and I hadn't tried to keep working on this project . The answer was to change the backend as suggested.

Comment: Also @DizietAsahi if you can change your answer to include changing the backend, I'll accept it. I'd just like to have it clear for other people.

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer. Although you were saying in your question that you could get some simple examples working and that only barplots were not working, which suggested that the backend was not the problem

Comment: Yeah my bad, I was trying it in a different notebook file that was provided as part of a tutorial. I didn't realize that the backend was being changed at the beginning of the file (in all honestly I didn't even know you could change backends until now).

Comment: I see, makes sense now. Glad I could help